# Reconstruction hierarchical model of miRNA transcription factor from miRNA microarray expression data?

Tags: bioinformatics

Does anyone know how to find the transcription factors of set of miRNA genes and reconstruct hierarchical miRNA transcription factors that regulate miRNA genes ?

Comment: This is probably a more appropriate question for a different forum, such as [BioStars](http://www.biostars.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRANSFAC database to find the Transcription Factors regulating a miRNA

http://www.gene-regulation.com/pub/databases.html